# What format is the output of HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile () and how to store it the best?

Tags: c#, hash, types, passwords

I'm using this function to generate a hash for a password and then store it in the database (SQL Server).

The code looks like this:

```
byte[] saltBytes = new byte[16];
new RNGCryptoServiceProvider ().GetBytes (saltBytes);
string salt = Convert.ToBase64String (saltBytes);
string saltedPasswordHash =
FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile (password + salt, FormsAuthPasswordFormat.SHA1.ToString ());
```

Now the question: in what format is the output of HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile () - do I store it as char(length) or nchar(length)?

Or is there any other preferred way to store the hash, maybe not as a string?

Any input and semi-relevant comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the record, this is NOT a good way to store a password hash.  See [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/39623) and, if need be my answer to [Drop in replacement for FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13527277/1967612) which details options on how to transition from this to PBKDF2, all in .NET - essentially, either transition everything to RFC2898DeriveBytes(pw,salt,iterations), everything to RFC2898DeriveBytes(HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(pw, “MD5”),salt,iterations), or upgrade users as they log in

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server supports binary columns (`binary(len)`, and `varbinary(len)`) designed to store binary data. You might want to consider using them. In that case, you could use classes such as `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed` directly, instead of `HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C#, it might be worth considering using a BCrypt hashing solution. It's designed on the BCrypt encryption algorithm by the guys writing OpenBSD and is a very strong algorithm. Best part is that you don't have to worry about salts (but they are there) and you can make salt generation hard as time goes on.

[BCrypt.net - Strong Password Hashing for .NET and Mono](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx)

Comment: BCrypt IS a good way to store a password hash, if you use a high enough work factor.  PBKDF2 and Scrypt are the other two current contenders, also with a high enough iteration count/work factor.  In all cases, @LeakyCode is right - BINARY(len) colunns for salt and hash both are the most efficient.