# Why i'm getting this error and what is the alternative solution of this

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, visual-studio-2015, hash-function

I'm trying to create a login page in which I'm trying to use Form Authentication hash function but I'm getting this error message

> FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(string, string) is obsolete: the recommended alternative is to use membership APIs, such as Membership.CreateUser.....

Anyone please tell me what is wrong here and how fix this. Also if there is any alternate way to hash my passwords before storing it in db please let me know.
I'm using

> Visual Studio 2015 pro
>
> asp.net web site project

my declaration

```
string ax = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(_inPASSWORD.Text, "MD5");
```

Comment: The method you are using has been deprecated.  To ensure continued functionality, it is best not to use deprecated methods.  It is pointing you to use the Membership library.   This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527277/drop-in-replacement-for-formsauthentication-hashpasswordforstoringinconfigfile

Comment: MD5 is very insecure.

Comment: Security is _hard_.  Do not build your own authentication system; you will make subtle mistakes that can compromise your users.  You should use the built-in Membership system, as the error is telling you to.

Comment: I don't have any idea of membership system

Comment: Well, you left off the last part of the error message, which is: "For more information, see [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252463](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252463)". Click the link and read about the new features.

Comment: It's not an error. It's a warning. The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527277/drop-in-replacement-for-formsauthentication-hashpasswordforstoringinconfigfile