# cannot convert from "method group" to "string"

Tags: c#, html, database, web, hash

sorry to bother you all. I'm programming a website and i'm trying to hash the password before storing it in the database but I get the error. I've seen related answers which advice people to use ".ToString()", however when I try this it seems to create more errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
 try
            {
                //hashing attempt
                string hashresult = Convert.ToInt32(FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(TextBox4.Text.Trim, "SHA1")); //the error is on this line (TextBox4.Text.Trim)
                //.ToString()
                //end


                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

                if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    //if its closed the program will open it
                    con.Open();
                }
                //texbox info to SQL
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into user_master_tbl(name,email,dob,region,postcode,user_id,password) values(@name,@email,@dob,@region,@postcode,@user_id,@password)", con);
                //connecting textbox to the information typed in
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@region", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", TextBox6.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", TextBox9.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", hashresult);
                //firing connection to database
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Response.Write("<script>" + "alert('Account created successfully, please proceed to login to your account');" + "</script>");
            }```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox4.Text.Trim
```

...should be:

```
TextBox4.Text.Trim()
```

The whole line should look like this:

```
string hashresult = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(TextBox4.Text.Trim(), "SHA1");
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but that just gives me another error.

Comment: @MorganKeilty It has to be called as `Trim()`... so what's your next error?

Comment: @Morgan Presumably your next error is because you're trying to parse the text of a SHA1 hash (presumably represented by 40 hexadecimal characters) as an integer (made up of numeric characters only). Or perhaps it's a warning that the method you're using is obsolete.

Comment: @MorganKeilty nevermind… remove the `Convert.ToInt32()` part...

Comment: it says it is obsolete and that I should use membership api's but I don't know what that means...

Comment: @Morgan [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527277/drop-in-replacement-for-formsauthentication-hashpasswordforstoringinconfigfile) might help.

Comment: @MorganKeilty See my edit... obsolete is a warning, so it will compile, but you'll want to address that.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for helping me, sorry for nagging but how would I go about addressing this problem?

Comment: @MorganKeilty John's link is probably a good place to start with that.

Comment: I recommend taking note of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004485/3181933) on the question I linked. The problem with your current method (based on the drop in replacement) is that two users with the same password will appear the same in your database. Should your database be compromised this makes it very easy to 1) identify users with the same password, and 2) perform dictionary attacks on the hashed passwords. Secure password storage should, at the very minimum, employ a salt. Modern techniques also expand on this by using key derivation, and a pepper.

Comment: I recommend reading [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) as a starting point. Secure user password storage is something you should definitely invest time in.