# .NET Core version of FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile

Tags: .net-core

Is there a way to test a password against the old FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile in .NET Core 6?

I am rewriting a 10 year old .NET MVC app in Angular and .NET Core. The passwords are currently stored in the DB using FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile. I want to give a grace period where if a user fails authentication with the new authentication scheme I can test it with the old method and if if passes with FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile then I can update the hash stored in the DB. This means most regular users will not see any interruption to the new system.

I was thinking I could have an end point in the old .NET I could call but would rather do it in the new app.

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527277/drop-in-replacement-for-formsauthentication-hashpasswordforstoringinconfigfile